# Как получить дорогу между 2 точками?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Написал приложение, в нем есть функция
определения пути между 2 координатами. Делаю при помощи `Directions API`, и всё прекрасно работает.

Путь находится, дорога чертится между координатами. Но вот теперь надо сделать это в оффлайне. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для получения путей между 2 координат оффлайн? Допустим, получить массив точек и провести их линией без использования сторонних сервисов.

Comment: Вероятно вам поможет эти руководства: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/routing-offline.html ++ https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/maps-offline.html